# How to integrate with Stripe payment gateway from MacOS desktop swift application

Tags: swift, macos, stripe-payments

We have a MacOS desktop application written in Swift. When I try to integrate with Stripe payment gateway, it says platform not supported. I understand it will work in mobile. But what about desktop? Backend is not a problem. We have decided to use a spring boot application for backend.

Comment: What are you doing to "integrate" an app with the payment gateway?  Seems like a question for Stripe's customer support.

Comment: I am not a swift developer. My team-mates are. They are trying to use Stripe's iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use [Stripe's iOS SDK](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios) in a macOS application, but [Stripe's iOS SDK does not support macOS at this time](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/1577).

The best alternative would be a web-based Stripe integration that you link to from inside the app or display using a web view.

Comment: thanks for answering. Your answer helped me. Somebody closed my question which I think is unfair, because you understood my question & I understand your answer.